# How do I let a user set 4 points on an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, image-processing

I want to make a tool in Python which allows a user to set 4 points on an image and then returns  positions of the points on the image in a format like this:

[[240, 250], [220, 1205], [500, 260], [549, 1206]]

Python 3.8.x | Windows 10

Comment: Where's the origin of the axis for these points? center? left bottom corner?

Comment: top left corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
points=[]
def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params): 
      
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 
        cv2.putText(img,str(x)+','+str(y),(x,y), font,1,(255, 0, 0),2) 
        cv2.imshow('image', img) 
        points.append((x, y))

img = cv2.imread('foto.jpg') 
cv2.imshow('image', img) 

cv2.setMouseCallback('image', click_event) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks this helped